# nltk corpus location on Mac Os

Tags: macos, python-2.7, nltk, eclipse-juno

Please,anyone using nltk on Eclipse IDE on Mac OS? I am trying to locate where the nltk corpus data is stored. I did some digging and found out they are located on my machine in this path:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/**init**.pyc
but when I moved into the nltk directory, I found a corpus folder but inside it is nothing similar to corpus. Anyone with tips on what next to do?

Comment: Have you downloaded the corpus already? It doesn't come with the base installation.

Comment: @MattDMo, it doesn't? I thought it comes with it since I found the corpus folder in the nltk directory. So, any tip on how to download the corpus?

Comment: Print `nltk.data.path` to see where NLTK searches for corpora on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corpora are not distributed as part of the base `nltk` package, as not all users of the module need them, and many of them are quite large - last I checked, there was one that was listed as 1.7 GB, not a trivial download for just about anyone.

However, if you read the excellent NLTK [docs](http://www.nltk.org/data.html), you'll immediately be shown how to select corpora for download:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

This will open a nice Tk-based GUI (in appropriate environments) or a text-based one and allows you to search for, select, and download corpora of interest, or even get everything, which is known in highly technical circles as "the whole shebang." You can even choose the directory in which to store your freshly-downloaded corpora. Easy!

The `corpus` directory that you somehow found contains the source code for [`nltk.corpus`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html), which has tools for dealing with corpora, not the actual corpora themselves.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, it seems to default to your home directory, so `/Users/X/nltk_data`. But, it is dependent upon where you installed it. As per MattDMo's comment, opening the GUI can give you more answers if you can't find what you need:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

If you want to just install it at a specific location, consider the command line option (which can also be useful for Docker and scripting):

```
python3 -m nltk.downloader -d /Users/X/nltk_data all
```